# Remove subdirectories from String in Dataframe Column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, split

I am trying to use l and rsplit to remove the subdirectories from this dataframe and preserve just the file name in the dataframe's column.

```
import pandas as pd
data = ['D:/xyz/abc/123/file_1.txt', 'D:/xyz/abc/file2.txt', 'D:/xyz/file_2.txt']
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data[0].str.rsplit('/').str[3]
```

Returns:

```
Out[1]: 
0          123
1    file2.txt
2          NaN
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

As you can see, this does not preserve just the txt file names regardless of the `str[]` function.

Desired output:

```
Out[1]: 
0    file_1.txt
1    file2.txt
2    file_2.txt
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try `data[0].str.rsplit('/').str[-1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `rsplit` with limit 1 and pick last item

```
data[0].str.rsplit('/', n=1).str[-1]

Out[194]:
0    file_1.txt
1     file2.txt
2    file_2.txt
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use `os.path.split` to get the last section of the path

https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html?highlight=path#os.path.split

```
import os

f = lambda x: os.path.split(x)[1]
data[0] = data[0].map(f)
```